# swprintf not converting values

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the function as a way to display the X and Y values of the mouse in a Win32 application. It replaces the x value, but for the y it sets it to zero. I cannot figure out why, and I have set a breakpoint during the application. Y is not 0.

Edit
I changed the data type to int and for some reason it is now working. I originally had it at the long long because I was handling the input differently, and the function required that data type. I forgot to change it back. I am not quite sure why it did not work with long long though.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

static long long x = -1, y = -1;

switch (message)
{
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        x = LOWORD(lParam);
        y = HIWORD(lParam);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0, TRUE);

        break;
    }
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(lParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        RECT rect;
        rect.left = x + 20;
        rect.top = y - 20;
        rect.right = x + 200;
        rect.bottom = y + 200;

        wchar_t displayMessage[100];
        swprintf(displayMessage, 100, L"(%d, %d)", x, y);

        DrawText(hdc, displayMessage, -1, &rect, NULL);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot buffer length as a second argument, [see the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/swprintf/).

```
wchar_t displayMessage[100];
swprintf(displayMessage, 100, L"(%d, %d)", x, y);
```

**Update:** Use `%lld` for `long long`.

Comment: You mean the value of `displayMessage` is like "(123, 0)"? Make sure `y` is an integral data and it isn't really zero.

Comment: I did. I set a breakpoint to see what the value is during execution. It's not 0.

Comment: Well, I suggest your problem is solved. Convert `x` and `y` to int, or use `%lld` specifier instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is not the correct identifier for a `long long`.

If you insist on using the C language `swprintf`, change the variables to `int`.  Or use `%lld`.  Or cast them as done below.

```
swprintf(displayMessage, 100, L"(%d, %d)", (int)x, (int)y);
```

**Edit:**

If you dislike the C language, you don't have to use it in this context.

This will also work, regardless of what integer types are used.

```
    std::wstringstream stream;
    stream << L"(" << x << L", " << y << L")";
    DrawText(hdc, stream.str().c_str(), -1, &rect, NULL);
```

Comment: Ah. That would explain it. Any idea why it worked for x and not y though?

Comment: @Emrys90 It wouldn't always work for `x` either.  Because your `x` and `y` arguments are too big, `swprintf` is effecively looking at half of `x` for the first number, and the other half of `x` for the second.  `swprintf` is not type-safe.

Comment: I changed them to int. I dislike all this C language things, but most Win32 functions require those data types. I am unfamiliar with them, so I do not always get it right.

Comment: I tried doing something similar to that. It says type const char * is not compatible with LPCWSTR.